# Python subprocess.run to execute bash commands via ssh

Tags: python-3.x, bash, ssh, subprocess

I am currently creating a function that will run at least 2 bash commands on a remote system via subprocess.run module because I need to capture the return code as well.

The example bash commands is `ssh username@ipaddress 'ls && exit'`
This will basically print out the contents of the remote home directory and exit the terminal created.

This works when using `os.system("ssh username@ipaddress 'ls && exit'")` but will not capture the return code.

In subprocess.run

```
### bashCommand is "ssh username@ipaddress 'ls && exit'"
bashCommand = ['ssh', f"username@ipaddress", "'ls && exit'"]
output = subprocess.run(bashCommand)
```

However when the subprocess.run command was run,

1. the terminal says that `bash: ls && exit: command not found`
2. the return code is 127 (from `output.returncode`)

Comment: `"'ls && exit'"` -> `"ls && exit"`